# What is the name of this vectorial transformation: $T: (x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

What is the name of the transformation $T$ such that

> $$T: (x, y) \mapsto (y, x) \text ?$$

Comment: It's the action of the Weyl group.

Comment: I believe its name is "T"

Comment: @Thorgott Nailed it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a reflection on the line $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x=y\}$.

Comment: That's right. But I expected an own name for the reflection over the bisector. Someone told me that the name was the reciprocal transformation. I wanted to ask here and see what other people think about, but nobody come with such name. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be too, **the aditive inverse of the conjugation of the left rotation map**.

Since $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2,~ z=x+iy\mapsto (x,y)$,
then if $T$ maps  $(x,y)\to(y,x)$ , you can think  that $T$ maps $z=x+iy$ to $w=y+ix$.

This operation could be archieved by $-\overline{iz}=-(\overline{ix+i^2y}) = -(\overline{-y+ix}) = -(-y-ix) = w$

since $iz$ is the rotation of $z$ by $90°$ degrees to the left, this is a rotation map.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a special name.  But it happens to be reflection about the line $y=x$.  And its matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, rel the standard basis.

It's also a permutation matrix.